# How to use web3js to call a function with "payable" and transfer some ether to contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, payable

My code is like this :

```
gameInstance.initGame.sendTransaction({from: webInstance.eth.coinbase, to: contractAddress, value: webInstance.toWei(person_num, "ether")});
```

Of course, it doesn't work very well.
Codes in the function has been executed, but ether haven't been transferred.
And value of the variable "person_num" is not 0.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
gameInstance.initGame({from: web3.eth.coinbase, to: contractAddress, value: web3.toWei(person_num, "ether")});
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work...[br /]I also tried add the second parameter, like below:[br /]`gameInstance.initGame({from: webInstance.eth.coinbase, to: contractAddress, value: webInstance.toWei(person_num, "ether")}, function(err, res){
            console.log(err);
            console.log(res);
        });`[br /]And it doesn't work either

Comment: if the code executed and didn't show any error by web3. then kindly check your solidity function 'initGame' and ensure that you have write the right code to transfer the ether

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tested it in Ethereum Wallet and the function works ok. So I think maybe the function is right?